# Prestashop supplier module

Tags: php, shopping-cart, prestashop

Any one knows if prestashop is providing supplier module?

I want to create something like " add suppliers from prestashop admin, and they should allowed to insert product and see their product order etc..."

Is it possible in prestashop? If yes any one can say which extension need to install?

If its not providing such, is there any other open source which providing such functions?

Answer (score 1):

I understand it like you want suppliers to have access to your back office so they can add new products?

Just create a new employee profile (under Employees > Profiles) and give the new profile permission to add new products (under Employees > Permissions).

Answer (score 1):

supplier is a attribute of the product and employee is another part in prestashop we have to marge ps_employee and ps_supplier or when add an employee then after get his last insert id , we have to insert same name in ps_supplier table with employee id.

1. add a column in ps_supplier -> id_employee.
2. add employee after insert the employee detail take his last insert id

if ($this->context->employee->id == Tools::getValue('id_employee'))

in \controllers\admin\AdminEmployeeController.php

(i am not complete this if any one know then help me . )

insert in ps_supplier table with his id_employee

3. select supplier from ps_supplier where id_employee == $loggedinemployee